# 3 Circles Around 3D Cursor/Origin Point

Tags: 3d-cursor, origin

What are these three circles around my 3D cursor/point of origin, and how do I disable them? They are definitely linked to my model because when I select the model the circles glow orange, when I deselect the circles go grey. When I hide the mesh the circles disappear. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given your object a *Physics > Force Field*, just remove it:

[image]

Comment: No idea how that happened, but thank you. Much appreciated!